# How to read activity GPS track from Health Connect?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fitness-api, healthconnect

I'm building a Kotlin project in Android Studio and having troubles grabbing GPS data from Health Connect. I went for a walk, synced my FitBit to Health Connect, and now I'd like to grab the GPS Track from my activity and use my app to process the lat/lon data into a "fastest times" list. Grabbing the lat/lon data seems to be the toughest part.

Here is the important bit. It reads all ExerciseSessionRecords within the past month from the Health Connect cloud:

```
val request = ReadRecordsRequest(
    recordType = ExerciseSessionRecord::class,
    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(from, to)
)
val response = healthConnectClient.readRecords(request)
```

There are recordTypes for CervicalMucusRecord and SexualActivityRecord but no LocationRecord??? Here's the full list of recordTypes: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/connect/client/records/package-summary#classes

And here's the data contained in ExerciseSessionRecord. Again, no Lat/Lon positions:

```
ExerciseSessionRecord(
    startTime: Instant,
    startZoneOffset: ZoneOffset?,
    endTime: Instant,
    endZoneOffset: ZoneOffset?,
    exerciseType: Int,
    title: String?,
    notes: String?,
    metadata: Metadata
)
```

And here is the code I've been testing out (logcat output at the end):

MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val permissionsLauncher = PermissionController.createRequestPermissionResultContract()
        val permissions = setOf(
            HealthPermission.getReadPermission(ExerciseSessionRecord::class)
        )
        var sessionsList: MutableState<List<ExerciseSessionRecord>> = mutableStateOf(listOf())


        // Catch the result from the system's permissions dialog
        val requestPermissions =
            registerForActivityResult(permissionsLauncher) { granted ->
                if (granted.containsAll(permissions)) {
                    // Permissions successfully granted
                    // PERMISSIONS: Set<string> as of Alpha11
                    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity: Permissions granted: $granted")
                    syncJob.cancel(CancellationException("Permissions have changed. Try again."))
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity: Lack of permissions")
                }
            }

        // Check for permissions
        suspend fun checkPermissionsAndRun(healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient) {
            // For alpha09 and lower versions, use getGrantedPermissions(PERMISSIONS) instead
            val granted = healthConnectClient.permissionController.getGrantedPermissions()
            if (granted.containsAll(permissions)) {
                // Permissions already granted; proceed with inserting or reading data.
                Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity: Permissions have already been granted")
                val now = Instant.now()
                val request = ReadRecordsRequest(
                    recordType = ExerciseSessionRecord::class,
                    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(now.minusSeconds(2592000), now)
                )
                val response = healthConnectClient.readRecords(request)
                sessionsList.value = response.records
            } else {
                // Launch system dialog to select permissions
                requestPermissions.launch(permissions)
            }
        }

        // Health Connect Button
        buttonHealthConnect.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            progressBarFragment.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            initSyncJob()

            val context = this
            CoroutineScope(IO + syncJob).launch {
                delay(2000)
                if(isSDKAvailable()) {
                    val healthConnectClient = HealthConnectClient.getOrCreate(context)
                    checkPermissionsAndRun(healthConnectClient)

                    var result = ""
                    var type = ""
                    for(value in sessionsList.value){
                        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity type = ${value.exerciseType}")
                        type = when (value.exerciseType) {
                            8 -> "Cycling"
                            79 -> "Walking"
                            else -> "Other"
                        }
                        result = result.plus("${type}: ${value.startTime}\n")
                    }
                    textViewResults.setText(result)
                    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity: \nReturned data from Health Connect: \n$result")
                    syncJob.complete()
                } else {
                    syncJob.cancel(CancellationException("Cancelled: SDK unavailable"))
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.zoomzoom.fitnessappstest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FitnessAppsTest"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name="com.fitnessappstest.ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Required to specify which Health Connect permissions the app can request -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_EXERCISE" />

    <queries>
        <!-- Declare Health Connect visibility -->
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.healthdata" />
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

logcat Results:

```
[-- Clicked Health Connect Button --]
MainActivity: SDK is available
MainActivity: 
    Returned data from Health Connect: 
MainActivity: syncJob complete
[-- Approved permissions in permissionLauncher --]
Permissions granted: [android.permission.health.READ_EXERCISE]


MainActivity: SDK is available
MainActivity: Permissions have already been granted
MainActivity type = 8
MainActivity type = 8
MainActivity type = 79
MainActivity type = 79
MainActivity: 
    Returned data from Health Connect: 
    Cycling: 2023-05-12T23:53:15.670Z
    Cycling: 2023-05-18T01:30:27.710Z
    Walking: 2023-06-09T04:30:50.131Z
    Walking: 2023-06-09T04:33:37.100Z
MainActivity: syncJob complete
```

P.S. Why Health Connect? Google Fitness API will be deprecated in 2024, moving to Health Connect. Samsung Health API requires approval, but they are no longer approving applications. Garmin Connect also requires approval. I haven't looked too hard into Garmin Connect. If approval is possible, maybe that's an option...

Answer (score 0):

You may use this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/health/connect/datatypes/ExerciseRoute.Location?hl=en) as a reference and I think this is supported in Android U. See this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect-guidelines/migrate/migrate-from-android-t-to-u) on how to migrate from Android T (13) to Android U (14)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).